# Need to find all tuples in two relations that do not participate in their natural join

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Here is the schema:

```
Student-schema =(studentnum, name, standing, gpa, major)
Class-schema = (schedulenum, semester, department, classnum, days, time, place, enrollment)
Instructor-schema = (name, department, office)
Teaches-schema = (name, schedulenum, semester)
Taking-schema = (studentnum, schedulenum, semester, grade)
```

I have to write a query that finds all tuples in student and taking that don't participate in the natural join of student and taking.  The result is a single relation with tuples from both student and taking that are padded with nulls appropriately.

The only idea I can come up with is to get the full join of student/taking and then keep the tuples that are left over after removing the natural join tuples.  But I'm not sure how to go about this.  Here's the best solution I've come up with so far, but I'm getting no rows selected.  I'm pretty sure I should have some results.  I'm just looking for any suggestions that a SQL pro might be willing to share.

```
SELECT*
FROM student full join taking ON student.studentnum = taking.studentnum
MINUS
SELECT*
FROM student,taking
WHERE student.studentnum = taking.studentnum;
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Can you add some sample data and the desired output? (Btw: a "natural" join is the same as a "regular" join, only without specifying column names - which is usually considerd bad style due to the implicit column name matching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sql code works in Oracle! you should replace full outer join and natural join in order to work in your DBMS.

(
    SELECT * FROM student NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN taking
) 
MINUS 
(
    SELECT * FROM student NATURAL INNER JOIN taking
)

Comment: My query above works, but it returns no rows when I am pretty sure it should.  Also, your query doesn't work in oracle.  I even added the ON constraint after your full join, but it says:  ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: You were right, I forgot to add "natural" keyword. just a question, you need all fields of both relations ?

Comment: How is that statement different to what the questions contains? It simply uses a different syntax, but doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: Well lo and behold, that did it.  It just needed to be natural.  Thank you for your help @MajidDarabi !

Comment: I do have a small follow-up question.  Is there a difference between NATURAL JOIN and NATURAL INNER JOIN?  From my understanding, inner join is a cross product if not followed by an ON constraint.  So, so a NATURAL INNER JOIN is just a cross product with a natural join, I'm assuming.  Which would make me think there is no difference.  Just curious.  EDIT:  Oh, and yes, I needed all fields, null padded and all, of the relations.